# How display img in index.php

Tags: wordpress

I have themplate it works fine no problem.

when I try to convert the themplate to theme wordpress, I copy all the content to 
`index.php` theme inside the the content I got the below code:

```
<ul>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="box-1">
                                        <img src="images/page1-img1.jpg" alt="" /> <a href="#">bora-bora</a>
 <span>from $458</span> 
                                        <p>Praesent vestibulum aenean
                                            <br>nonummy hendrerit mauris.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="box-1">
                                        <img src="images/page1-img2.jpg" alt="" /> <a href="#">Hawaii</a>
 <span>from $458</span> 
                                        <p>Praesent vestibulum aenean
                                            <br>nonummy hendrerit mauris.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
```

the images are not display on the screen.

I can see my theme in url:`http://127.0.0.1/www/www1/wordpress/Heb/wordpress/

to see the img I can see with full path:

`http://127.0.0.1/www/www1/wordpress/Heb/wordpress/wp-content/themes/yossi_theme/images/page1-img1.jpg`

if I click right mouse on the picture wich I can't see, and copy target url,I got the adress:

```
http://127.0.0.1/www/www1/wordpress/Heb/wordpress/images/slide-1.jpg
```

and the error :`The requested URL /www/www1/wordpress/Heb/wordpress/images/slide-1.jpg was not found on this server.`

what should I change here `<img src="images/page1-img1.jpg" alt="" />` to display the img ?

many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said that the full path of your image is

```
http://127.0.0.1/www/www1/wordpress/Heb/wordpress/wp-content/themes/yossi_theme/images/page1-img1.jpg
```

then you can try this

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/images/yourImageName.png" alt="" />
```

instead of

```
<img src="images/yourImageName.png" alt="" />
```

`get_template_directory_uri()` will return your `theme` folder's path, i.e.

```
http://127.0.0.1/www/www1/wordpress/Heb/wordpress/wp-content/themes/yossi_theme
```

Answer (score 0):

If this image is a part of your layout (not part of the content), you can either use entire path (eg. `http://localhost/image.jpg`) or place it in your theme's directory (let's say, `[your theme]/images` and then use `<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/image.jpg" alt="">`.

If this is a part of your content (post, page, whatever), upload this file through WordPress admin and place it from there.